# 2 Way binding issue using Fast-UI + Vue.js ver. 2.6.11

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, fast-ui

### This was tested on the verions (`package.json`):

```
{
  "name": "fast-ui-vuejs-ver-2611-binding-issue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/fast-components": "^2.10.1",
    "@microsoft/fast-element": "^1.5.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "4.1.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-selector": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "4.1.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
}
```

## Preconditions

0. open the sandbox using [this URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-ui-vue-js-ver-2-6-11-binding-issue-forked-xi1pv?file=/README.md);
1. wait until everything is installed;
2. wait until you see the slider on the right-hand side of the screen.

### Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. drag the thumb(handle) of the slider forwarnd and back;
2. have a look at the value (it has changed as expected);
3. click on <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> buttons;
4. try to use slider again;
5. get back to <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> button, and click one or another.

###### Actual result:

Binding stops working or at least works not as intended after interacting with different components/elements

###### Expected Result:

It must work after any interaction it has.

###### The things I have tried:

- v-model;
- custom-bining directive for events (onchange, drag).

code example of cusotom binding directive:

**Implementation** file

```js
Vue.directive("cd-bind", {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    const inputHandler = (event) =>
      (vnode.context.$data[binding.expression] = event.target.value);
    el.addEventListener("input", inputHandler);
    el.addEventListener("change", inputHandler);
    el.addEventListener("slide", inputHandler);
  },
});
```

**Usage:**

```html
<fast-slider
      v-cd-bind="value"
      :value="value"
      :min="0"
      :max="20"
></fast-slider>
```

###### Additional information:

After an element loses focus and another element gets focused, binding (or some part of it stops working).

[Video on this issue](https://www.loom.com/share/512f18e2640f4d19a774a84519aa6cb2)

The suggestion made by `"EisenbergEffect"` that may help someone to find out the way to fix it
[site](https://discord.com/channels/449251231706251264/744625350910148690/831912905997549600):

> "For Aurelia, we had to add some special configuration to enable better
> two-way binding. I'm guessing that there's a similar need with Vue.
> Typically in a two-way or model bind scenario the framework needs to
> know how to correlate event names with the properties that change so
> it can add event listeners. My guess is that Vue doesn't know what
> events to attach because it only has code to handle built-in elements.
> As a next step, I think you may want to take a look and see if Vue
> offers an API to provide that data to their model binding system.
> Hopefully they do. In that case, we would just need to set that up
> properly for the components we publish...and add that to our
> documentation for Vue. Another issue may be related to whether Vue's
> binding is setting properties or attributes. They can be different and
> tend to be a little when it comes to input elements. Does: value set
> the value attribute or the value property?"

###### Main component code:

```html
<template>
  <fast-card>
    <span style="color: white"
      >Current value:
      <b style="color: red; font-size: 150%">{{ value }}</b></span
    >
    <fast-slider
      :value="value"
      :max="max"
      :min="min"
      ref="comp"
      @change="change($event)"
    >
      <div
        slot="track"
        class="time-seeker__played"
        :style="{ width: timePlayedPercentage + '%' }"
      ></div>
    </fast-slider>

    <fast-card>
      <fast-button @click="value = value > 0 ? value - 1 : value"
        >-</fast-button
      >
      <fast-button @click="value = value < 20 ? value + 1 : value"
        >+</fast-button
      >
    </fast-card>
  </fast-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      value: 3,
      min: 0,
      max: 20,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    timePlayedPercentage: function () {
      let value = Math.round((this.value * 100) / this.max);
      // console.log(value, "%");
      return value;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    change(e) {
      this.value = +e.target.value;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
div {
  width: 100%;
}

.time-seeker__played {
  transition: width 75ms cubic-bezier(0.86, 0.05, 0.4, 0.96);
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15%;
}

fast-card {
  margin-block: 1rem;
}

fast-button {
  margin-inline-end: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### After make some inquiries to the FAST-UI team, they have created a few PR in their repository:

- [rfc: separate 'value' and 'initial-value' concepts for FAST form-associated controls #5119](https://github.com/microsoft/fast/issues/5119);
- [feat: adds a currentValue property to form-associated #5298](https://github.com/microsoft/fast/pull/5298).

After they have updated the core code of this project, this 2-way binding has disappeared!

However, to make thins work, they have implemented a new HTML attribute called `current-value` (or `currentValue` in JS) that is in a change of it.

This feature is available in:

- `@microsoft/fast-foundation@2.23.0`;
- or `@microsoft/fast-components@2.14.2`.

### The difference in HTML/Vue components

#### Before

```
<fast-slider
      :value="value"
      :max="max"
      :min="min"
      ref="comp"
      @change="change($event)"
    >
```

#### After

```
<fast-slider
      :current-value="value"
      :max="max"
      :min="min"
      ref="comp"
      @change="change($event)"
    >
```

Here is the version that works perfectly thanks to FAST-UI team:
[open workable sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-ui-vue-js-ver-2-6-11-binding-issue-hfq15?file=/src/components/BindingIssue.vue:450-579)

Also, there is another PR that is pending as for 28.10.2021
[feat: add current-checked attribute to checkable form controls #5326](https://github.com/microsoft/fast/pull/5326) that will add `current-checked` attribute to make it responsive to UI/JS changes.